# How do I provide an environment to a script started like bash -c bla.sh

Tags: bash, bashrc

I noticed that e.g. ~/.bashrc is not sourced when starting a script with bash -c bla.sh.
So how else can I provide environment variables?
Preferably without explicitly setting them in the invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide them on the command line (which you've stated you don't want):

```bsh
MYVAR=hello ./bla.sh
```

---

You can set and export them first:

```bsh
MYVAR=hello
export MYVAR
./bla.sh
```

or

```bsh
export MYVAR=hello
./bla.sh
```

---

You can set up an "*environment*" file, and source this within your script (this is how `~/.bashrc` is handled):

```bsh
echo "MYVAR=hello" > test.env
./bla.sh
```

Within `bla.sh`:

```bsh
source test.env
echo ${MYVAR}
```

Note that a `.` (period / dot) is an alias for `source`, so you  could put `. test.env` in place of `source text.env`.

If you want to import your `~/.bashrc`, then you *could* use `source ~/.bashrc`... but not that this will typically configure a number of things for a terminal / interactive environment - which is not how scripts run.

Comment: Thank you. I chose to write a wrapper script, which sources the environment before running the actual script, like so: `source test.env; $@`. I didn't tell that bla.sh is just a placeholder for possibly many different scripts or commands.